# How to add a suffix to all the files

Tags: powershell

I need to add the same suffix to all of the files.
I used the code provided below. It adds '2013' after file extension e.g. Alfa Ltd.doc2013.

```
dir *.* | ren -Newname {$_.name + "2013"}
```

What I want to achieve is to add '2013' to all of the filenames. 
Alfa Ltd. 2013.doc
Beta Ltd. 2013.doc
so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to put it all together:

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + ' 2013' + $_.Extension} -whatif
```

Comment: Thanks! I amended the code ```dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + ' 2013' + $_.Extension}```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official website first [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6)
this command rename all files in current directory

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('.txt','.log') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dir *.* | % {Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Basename + ' 2013' + $_.Extension)}
```

Also I've added Space before the `2013` you can replace it with dash or whatever